# cannot use GCMRegistrar?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

cannot use the GCMRegisterar from gcm.jar which i have added to build path ,but still i am getting this message in logcat.

```
07-12 14:29:08.825: I/dalvikvm(23536): Could not find method com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId, referenced from method com.example.registration_id.MainActivity.onCreate
```

Comment: How you have added the jar to the build path?

Comment: @darkcrow I copied the gcm.jar file from android folder in C drive into my eclipse project ,then right clicked on it and selected buildpath>add to build path. it got added in referenced library in package explorerof my project.

Comment: I am not petty sure if it required but you need to create a /libs folder and copy gcm.jar into that and then build it.

Comment: @darkcrow Thank you,your suggestion has solved the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a `/libs` folder and copy `gcm.jar` into that and then build it.